# Чисто виртуальные функции и абстрактные классы

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование, виртуальная-функция

При написании очередного учебного проекта столкнулся с интересным случаем.

По задумке, мне нужно определить набор сущностей (классов), которые вытекают из некоторой общности. Хорошо сюда ложится пример из линейной алгебры - матрицы и вектора. Над матрицами и векторами определен набор операции, которые во многом схожи, и некоторые даже выполняются одинаково. Остановимся на на таких вещах, как норма и взятие единичного вектора или матрицы. Сходу в голову приходит задекларировать абстрактный базовый класс, который определит данные, которыми они будут оперировать, и чисто виртуальные функции взятие единичного объекта и нормы.

Вытекает следующая проблема: если взятие нормы - операция, которая возвращает число (double для определенности). И тут все хорошо ложиться в логику абстрактного класса и чисто виртуальной функции. Но получение единичного объекта - не совсем: метод взятия единичного объекта должен вернуть новый объект того же типа. А, как мы знает, при попытки декларирования чисто виртуального метода, возвращающего абстрактный тип, получим ошибку компиляции.

Приведу пример словам:

```
    #include <stddef.h>


    namespace linalg_wrong {

        template <class LINALG_VECTOR> LINALG_VECTOR identity(LINALG_VECTOR& obj)
        {
            return obj.identity();
        }

        template <class LINALG_VECTOR> LINALG_VECTOR norm(LINALG_VECTOR& obj)
        {
            return obj.norm();
        }

        class __linalg_base {
        protected:
            double* data_;
            size_t size;

        public:
            explicit __linalg_base(double*, const size_t&);
            virtual ~__linalg_base(){ if (data_ != nullptr) delete [] data_; }

            virtual __linalg_base identity()=0; // error
            virtual double norm()=0;
        };

        class vector : public __linalg_base {
        public: 
            vector identity();
            double norm();
        };

    }
```

Тут я определил шаблонные функции взятия единичного объекта и нормы, которые являются просто обертками над методами класса. Затем, для меня, логично потребовать на уровне соглашения, что все объекты определяемые в данной библиотеке должны быть унаследованы от __linalg_base. Что само по себе накладывает обязательство переопределения интересующих нас методов у всех потомков по средствам механизма чисто виртуальных функции.

При попытке компиляции (gcc 8.3.0) получим ошибку:

```
ошибка: некорректный абстрактный возвращаемый тип «linalg_wrong::__linalg_base»
virtual __linalg_base identity()=0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стоит возвращать не объект, а указатель на `__linalg_base`, а лучше `std::unique_ptr<__linalg_base>`

Answer (score 0):

Простейшим примером решения данной проблемы может быть написание "прокси"-метода, который вернул бы данные не в виде абстрактного класса, а в виде какого-либо другого объекта. А затем определить конструктор, к которому можно скастовать полученный объект.

Например так:

```
    #include <stddef.h>
    #include <utility>
    #include <iostream>

    using __raw_vector = std::pair<double*, size_t>;

    namespace linalg_solution {

        template <class LINALG_VECTOR> LINALG_VECTOR identity(LINALG_VECTOR& obj)
        {   
            return obj.identity();
        }

        template <class LINALG_VECTOR> LINALG_VECTOR norm(LINALG_VECTOR& obj)
        {
            return obj.norm();
        }

        class __linalg_base {

        protected:
            double* data_;
            size_t size_;

            virtual __raw_vector identity_()=0; // proxy-method

        public:
            explicit __linalg_base(double*, const size_t&);
            virtual ~__linalg_base(){ if (data_ != nullptr) delete [] data_; }

            virtual double norm()=0;
        };

        class vector : public __linalg_base {
        protected:
            __raw_vector identity_();

        public:
            explicit vector(const __raw_vector&);

            double norm();

            vector identity()
            {
                return static_cast<vector>(this->identity_());
            }
        };    
    }
```

Это самый простой способ, который я нашёл, чтобы решить данную проблему. Скорее всего есть что-то более элегантное.